# Anyone here using anything from the API 500 series 

Tags: hardware

Been really interested in trying out the 500 series lunchbox and several of the 3rd party modules, seems like a nice adaptable and compact unit.

Anyone have any love or hate stories? 
Or better yet, recommended modules or unheard of ones etc

thanks
C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got 550As and 550Bs in my music studio.

They sound great on certain things. Other things, not so much. If used with certain pieces of gear they need line drivers because they load down the signal too much.

I kind of wish they had more frequency options and Qs, but such is the case with most vintage gear. You're not going to use these to cut out offending frequencies, mostly to boost overall high-end or low-end...

I liken them to the GML EQ - they add a bit of a sandy graininess to the high-end when accentuated.

Some things like crash cymbals tend to sound great through them. A voice, however, like a VO or close-miked dialogue, sound horrible I've found.

Good luck in your search.

Answer (score 0):

I dig the format myself and have a full lunchbox. I basically built it so I could have what amounts to a stereo channel strip I can easily move anywhere around the studio. For instance when I'm sitting in front of a rack of noise making toys tweaking knobs.

My rig consists of pairs of Shadow Hills pres, Burgin McDaniel Komits and A-Designs EM PEQs. Still on my list to get are a pair of the Harrison EQs, Standard Audio Level-ORs and Tonelux comps.

The 500 series format has grown exponentially in the last couple years and continues to do so. Radial has embraced it and is creating some interesting products, one being the Workhorse rack. There are a number of manufacturers that are beginning to release modules at less expensive price points. Lindell Audio is about to launch their new line of 500 modules at musikmesse at $299 per module. Pretty reasonable for a 500 module assuming they sound good. Lindell makes some amazing sounding stuff so I have high hopes for these.

This subject has been beaten to death over at Gearslutz. I would highly recommend dropping by there and doing some digging. There is a wealth of 500 info there.

Comment: !!! I'm newly aware of this format, and so I did a quick search for the modules you mentioned. That's a +$7k portable stereo channel strip! Yeow. This boy can dream.

Answer (score 0):

If you are located in North County San Diego and want to try them out, we rent these units to your flavor of customization. Only $89/day. We are called ANALOG SOURCE RENTALS - Renting these HIGH-END ANALOG OUTBOARD units including Neve, SSL, API, Chandler Limited, Avedis and more. Find us online through Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/AnalogSourceRental